# Google end point client library for GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-endpoints

Does anyone know if Google is planning to release a end point client library for GWT ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Google is no longer developing GWT ([on is own](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2012/120629-google-hands-gwt-to-committee.html)) so the answer is no BUT some people are creating GWT library to communicate with REST APIs (whatever the technology behind is: JAX-RS, endpoints ...).

Look at [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/)

> RestyGWT is a GWT generator for REST services and JSON encoded data
>   transfer objects.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I believe that endpoints supports both REST and RPC clients, and I thought GWT already supported RPC.  So couldn't GWT work that way?

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by RPC client [wikipedia RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)? A client using REST is a kind RPC client ... GWT-RPC is simply a generator to write JAVA servlets more easily + the client code associated.

Comment: Your comment makes sense, but the bullet points for cloud endpoints usually includes something like 'enables you to build REST and RPC APIs in App Engine', and I thought I read that the RPC interface was used for servicing iOS clients.  But perhaps I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Such a client library already exists:

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/

Comment: I see that the gwt-google-apis projects shows how to consume standard google services like 'calender', 'url shortener' etc from GWT. How can I consume an endpoint service that I have created ? For eg: I have an endpoint service [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/base=https://ishaportal.appspot.com/_ah/api) ? Any sample code would be very useful.

Comment: @Sathya Why don't you ask a new StackOverflow question asking for that? Your current question has been answered as it stands.